# Angular2 Rxjs 404 error

Tags: angular, rxjs, systemjs

I have the following error when trying to start my Angular2 application:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:55707/rxjs(…)
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Streak Maker</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
        },
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

boot.ts:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/> 

import {App} from './app.component';
import {bootstrap}  from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {APP_PROVIDERS} from './app.module';

bootstrap(App, [
    //ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    //HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS]);
```

I've tried putting paths for rxjs in the system.config (it doesn't work) but since I'm using the rxjs bundle I shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is in your `streak-maker/src/StreakMaker.Web/App/message-board/message-board.service.ts` file

You should import the `rxjs` module since it doesn't exist in the Rxjs library:

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import "rxjs"; // <-----

@Injectable()
export class MessageBoardService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  get() {
    return this._http.get('/api/messageboard').map(res => {
        return res.json();
    });
  }
}
```

You should use the following one (`rxjs/Rx`) instead:

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import "rxjs/Rx"; // <-----

@Injectable()
export class MessageBoardService {
  (...)
}
```

You're right: include the Rx.js file is enough to provide the Rxjs modules. No additional (explicit) configuration is required within `SystemJS.config`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks!  Mind telling how you tracked down the problem?

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, when SystemJS can't find a registered module (it's the case with Rxjs here since you include the `Rx.js` file), it tries then to load the module from an URL: http://<host>/<module-name>. So I guess that you tried to load the `rxjs` module but this module isn't provided by Rxjs. It's rather `rxjs/Rx`. So I looked for an import like this in your code: `import 'rxjs';`...

Comment: So once you specify a directory with the SystemJS map, you can reference any file specifically by importing `<package>/<filename>`? Assuming you have the defaultExtension set correctly.

Comment: This error message is quite misleading, it may not be exact issue, read on my experience @ http://phanikatakam.blogspot.in/2016/11/how-to-solve-white-page-error-in.html

Answer (score 0):

As noted by HydTechie (left in comment on Nov 25 '16 at 16:22), the error message can be very misleading.

My initial issue was that a CodeMagazine issue [May Jun 2017 "From Zero to Crud in Angular: Part 1"](http://www.codemag.com/article/1705021) had a typo using an import for 'rxjs/add/operator/throw' where the actual path should have been 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'.

But even after correcting, and attempting fixes noted here and elsewhere, I didn't get an accurate error from the Chrome dev tools console. It accused zone.js for looking at the non-existent throw.js library.

When i reviewed the same code in IE, i found I had a type-o in my componentUrl filename, which for some reason bubbled up out of my http service and was caught there an output to the console.

So HydTechie's rant blogspot, while not comprehensive, did correctly indicate that true errors aren't easy to find.

I found i didn't need to add anything beyond the angular quick start default rxjs: {defaultExtension:'js'} packages entry in my systemjs.config, and fix the import 'rxjs/add/operator/throw'; to be import 'rxjs/add/obserable/throw';

```
// the product service will call the webapi for product collections
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'; // fixed typo
```

from systemjs.config.js

```
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no 
extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
      './*.js': {
        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
      }
    }
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js' // this is fine as is
  }
}
```