# Unable to find the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following a few questions here, to try and resolve my issue. Originally, I keept getting this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I them looked at these two questions, and concluded that I am missing some additional properties in the configuration:

[Angular2 Rxjs 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239813/angular2-rxjs-404-error)  and [Where is angular2-polyfills now that non-beta Angular 2 is packaged as @angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034664/where-is-angular2-polyfills-now-that-non-beta-angular-2-is-packaged-as-angular) .

The missing property that I had to add in **systemjs.config.js** in order to get rid of the rxjs 404, is as follows:

```
rxjs: {
    main: '/bundles/Rx.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
},
```

However, now I keep getting an error by the zone.js file stating that my template is nowhere to be found.

```
zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3000/templates/Data.component.tpl.html 404 (Not Found)
```

I am using this template in this code: **/app/components/Data.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MyService} from "../service/MyService";
import {MyVo} from "../domain/MyVo";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '../templates/Data.component.tpl.html',
    providers: [MyService]
})

@Injectable()
export class DataComponent {

    public gotData: MyVo [];
    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {}

    getAllData(): void {
    this._myService.getAllData().subscribe(
        data => this.gotData= data, error=> console.log(error),
        () => console.log("getting all items complete"));
    }

}
```

My template is located under: **app/templates/** and is called **Data.component.tpl.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="getAllData()">
<label>Version Tracks</label>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<hr>
    <p style="color:red">{{error}}</p>
<h1>All Data</h1>
```

How do I get rid of this error? Do I need to set a different zone.js file to be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you've set your references relative to the current path. Try setting your template url absolute:

```
templateUrl: './app/templates/Data.component.tpl.html'
```

It could also be that you've set up your server in a way that its root is not who you think it is. Check your server settings as well.

Comment: I was under the impression that a ../ would go back. How do I set it to be relative? Not really sure I like this idea of hardcoded absolute path

Comment: I think now is the time to refer to the Angular2 docs ;) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html